# Virtual Earth and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, virtual-earth

I would like to use Virtual Earth on an ASP.NET MVC application for a client. What are the licenses available for commercial use?

Also, does anyone have a good example? I tried a few examples but they always end with 'Object is null' error in the java script code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nerddinner](http://nerddinner.com/) has [example code](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) to download.